# How can I reference another DB from a VS DB project?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012, schema-compare

We have several databases, say DB1, DB2, DB3 etc.

They have to have identical code base, so we use a DB project in Visual Studio 2012 and generate a SQL script for deployment based on comparison between the project and UAT/Prod DB1. Then this script is applied to DB1-DBn.

For the very first time in the history of this DB project I had to create a function that contained a hardcoded database name, example:

```
inner join DB1.schema.table1 as t1 on
```

And now the project cannot be built or comparison cannot be updated or script generated (Update and Generate Script buttons disabled) due to a number of errors pertaining to that database reference, as VS seems to believe that DB1 does not exist.

I tried to add a project level SQLCMD variable `$(DB)` and set it to `DB1` default value and use it as

```
inner join [$(DB1)].schema.table1 as t1 on
```

to work around the errors, but it did not seem to make any difference.

Edit:

A suggestion was made to add a circular project reference to itself and assign to it the same variable I was trying to add manually, not sure how to accomplish that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per this [article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/3eef14ee-511c-4f98-b2ec-d8a083efa3b4/sql-server-data-tools-71561?forum=sqltools) the reference should be added to a **manually extracted** `.dacpac` file as follows:

Extracted `.dacpac` file from the targed DB with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\120\sqlpackage.exe" /SourcePassword:p /SourceUser:u /Action:Extract /ssn:192.168.2.1 /sdn:DB1 /tf:DB1.dacpac
```

Included that as a database reference. It automatically assigned the correct SQLCMD variable name and the error disappeared.

From the source control point, even though when adding a database reference to a `.dacpac` file automatically creates a SQLCMD variable, it does not add the file to the project. The `.dacpac` file used still has to be added to the project as an existing item, which is kind of lame. Doing that in the solution explorer I encountered an error and had to do that through the team explorer instead, where that worked.